# Cannot run external program from eclipse neon

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime, external

I know there are a lot of questions like this, but they didn't really help.

I'm trying to make a program that prints out documents (a specific document), so I want to "run" the folder it's in, click up the document and hit CTRL+P. So I tried just using `Runtime`:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Users/Rasmus/Desktop/Notepad.lnk");
```

and I got the **error**:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\iNsaniTy\Desktop\Notepad.lnk": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

And then `ProcessBuilder` (never used it before, don't know what it is) which looks like

```
new ProcessBuilder("C:/Users/Rasmus/Desktop/Notepad.lnk").start();
```

And I got the same error. I have used the `Runtime` method before and it worked. I don't know if it matters, but I have downloaded the latest version of eclipse (eclipse neon) since then. Does any kind soul have any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@J Doe, .lnk is a short link for the actual executable. 
Your exception clearly mentions this.

Resolution will be to give path of actual executable. How you can check the path of the executable.

```
Right CLick on .lnk > Open Properties > Path in the Target will be the actual path of the executable.
```

Take the path of target and use it in your code for ProcessBuilder or  RUntime exec

Comment: Oh great, Thank you so much mate!

Comment: Mark this is correct answer if it is useful. This will help others as well doing similar action and getting the error